# Why can't I pass operator to a function from an other in C++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, operators

In my C++ homework (where I have to short different arrays with different methods), I run into a problem. I can't pass comp() from one function to another.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
void fooFunction(T arr[], int arraySize, Compare comp = Compare{})
{
    int endElem=arraySize-1;
    int beginElem =0;
    fooFunction2(arr, beginElem , endElem, arraySize, comp()); //I am getting the errors here
}

template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
void fooFunction2(T arr[], int beginElem, int endElem, int arraySize, Compare comp = Compare{})
{
    
}

struct string_size_less
{
    bool operator()(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) const
    {
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arrI[] = { 4, 5, 1, 4, 2};
    std::string arrS[] = {"Car", "Bicycle", "Metro", "Bike"};

    fooFunction(arrI, 5);
    fooFunction(arrS, 4, string_size_less());
    return 0;
}
```

At the moment I am getting:

```
error: no match for call to '(std::less<int>) ()'|
error: 'fooFunction2' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]|
```

What would be the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Try to understand what is forward declaration.

Comment: Looks like you are calling `comp`, not passing it. Clean that up and you'll find `fooFunction2` still can't be found because it's declared after where it's first used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed two things:

1. in your call to `fooFunction2(..)`, don't pass `comp()` but `comp`.
   If you add parantheses, you execute the comp-function, which fails because a comparing function needs arguments passed to it. Just passing `comp` instead will just tell it where to look for the function in question.
2. place the definition of `fooFunction2(..)` above where you call it. If you define it lateron, the compiler won't find the definition at the moment it finds the first call to it. (There might be compiler options to fix this). Just swapping the defintions is enough to fix it, though declaring it in a header file (especially in larger projects) might be a smoother way.
   This code compiles just fine:

   ```
    template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
    void fooFunction2(T arr[], int beginElem, int endElem, int arraySize, Compare comp = Compare{})
    {

    }

    template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
    void fooFunction(T arr[], int arraySize, Compare comp = Compare{})
    {
        int endElem=arraySize-1;
        int beginElem =0;
        fooFunction2(arr, beginElem , endElem, arraySize, comp); //I am getting the errors here
    }


    struct string_size_less
    {
        bool operator()(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) const
        {
            return a.size() < b.size();
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
    int arrI[] = { 4, 5, 1, 4, 2};
    std::string arrS[] = {"Car", "Bicycle", "Metro", "Bike"};

    fooFunction(arrI, 5);
    fooFunction(arrS, 4, string_size_less());
    return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you're passing `comp()` as the last argument instead of passing `comp`.

To **solve** this pass `comp` instead of `comp()` as shown below:

```
struct string_size_less
{
    bool operator()(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) const
    {
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
void fooFunction2(T arr[], int beginElem, int endElem, int arraySize, Compare comp = Compare{})
{
    
}
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
void fooFunction(T arr[], int arraySize, Compare comp = Compare{})
{
    int endElem=arraySize-1;
    int beginElem =0;
//----------------------------------------------------vvvv--->changed from comp() to comp
    fooFunction2(arr, beginElem , endElem, arraySize, comp);
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/e5n_wS4Na)

Moreover, before using a function you should have a declaration for that function. See in the working demo linked above.